# At what version of the SQL standard did arrays appear?

Tags: sql

There are various versions of the SQL standard: SQL86, SQL89, etc. From what version are arrays defined?

P.S. Please name a full reference book about the SQL standard (including SQL:2011).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a presentation from Jim Melton from Oracle that summarizes the new things in SQL:1999 and on slide 8, titled "New Data Types" it lists

```
ARRAY - _datatype ARRAY [n]
```

so I guess this was introduced in SQL:1999

The filename of the presentation is `sql1999_c4.pdf`.

I downloaded that ages ago (don't know from where), but searching for it, shows it's still available, e.g. here: https://www.cs.mtsu.edu/~csal/common/cs4560/sql1999_c4.pdf

You can also search for another presentation (which is from IBM) with the filename `sql1999_c3.pdf` which has also some information about the various versions of the SQL standard.

---

Nobody is going to give you "*a full reference book*" because (unfortunately) it is not free and if you want one, you have to pay for it. So giving it away would violate the copyright.